# select one element & not select parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use in listener jquery,i want some thing $(".parentClass:not(.childClass)").on("click",function(){}),but this code not work and when I click child div listener is run,I want only  parent is run;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  **[`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** for preventing parent event handler action

```js
// Handler for parent
$(".parentClass").on("click", function(e) {
  alert('hi')
});

// Handler for child
$('.childClass').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // preventing any parent handlers action
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentClass">
  parent1
  <div class="childClass">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

> **[`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** : Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Taken from **https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/**

Comment: No!I want if I click in child listener isn't run

Answer (score 0):

You need to check event target like so:

```
$(".parentClass").on("click",function(e){
   if($(e.target).hasClass('childClass')){
       return;
   }

   //do staff on exectly parent click
})
```